# How to strace all write calls (to stdout/stderr) from all child processes inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, strace

I'm running this command:

```
strace -f -e trace=desc ./my-program
```

(So you see I'm running the `-f` parameter)

Which lets me see the stdout/stderr `write` commands of the parent process:

```
[pid    10] 07:36:46.668931 write(2, "..\n"..., 454 <unfinished ...>

<stdout of ..>

<stdout other output - but I don't see the write commands - so probably from a child process>

[pid    10] 07:36:46.669684 write(2, "My final output\n", 24 <unfinished ...>

<stdout of My final output>
```

What I want to see is the other write commands.

This is running in a docker container being executed with:

```
docker run --privileged=true my-label/my-container
```

My question is: **How to strace all write calls (to stdout/stderr) from all child processes inside a docker container?**

EDIT:
Note that this application starts and stops in about 2 seconds. `strace` can follow its application cycle. But tools that expect it to hang around like a server process won't work. (Perhaps `sysdig` can be used for this - but I haven't seen an example of this model yet).

Comment: you may also consider `sysdig` which I believe has container support

Comment: thanks @thrig - I think that `sysdig` won't run against applications (ones that start and stop quickly) - only against server process that hang around perpetually. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: how would the kernel (where sysdig runs) not see a "quick" process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `strace` truncates string output - you have to explicitly tell it that you want more than the first n (10?) string chars. You do this with `-s 800`.

```
strace -s 800 -ff  ./myprogram
```

You can also get all the `write` commands by asking `strace` explicitly with `-e write`.

```
strace -s 800 -ff -e write  ./myprogram
```